# Microsoft Access 2013 - Variable in Table Data

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables, ms-access-2013, richtext

I'm using Access 2013 and CDO to send emails directly from my application.  I am working on building a form to allow users to compose emails based on saved templates.  The templates are stored in an Access Table and will use variables to populate the email with relevant data.  Treating the table data like code is proving difficult.  A simple, hypothetical example follows:

```
vExample = "1234"
tblEmailTemplate.EmailBody = "text " & vExample
```

When I populate txtEmailBody on the form, I get: **"text " & vExample**;

what I need is: **text 1234**

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!!

(If a rich text formatted text box is the only way forward maybe a link to a quick link to how to work with variables using RTF would be great)

Comment: I dont get where you have the table data? I think there might be a problem there, because normally what you want to do shouldn't be a problem. So: simplifying a problem is all ok. But not if you simplify the problem away ;) Post the problematic code please.

Comment: I'm using a bound form so there isn't any code other than what is in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution;

Change from

```
vExample = "1234"
tblEmailTemplate.EmailBody = "text " & vExample
```

to

```
vExample = "1234"
tblEmailTemplate.EmailBody = text [evExample]
strBody = Replace(tblEmailTemplate.EmailBody, "[[evExample]]", vExample)
```